# AVCaptureVideoDataOutput delegate not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

DidOutputSampleBuffer delegate not called, but I can not found any issue in my setup camera code. code in github: [Demo code](https://github.com/dulingkang/DMScanCode)

I print input output in my session, they are have values, and preset is also set, can anyone help me?

```
#import "DMVideoCamera.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DMVideoCamera()<AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>
@implementation DMVideoCamera

- (instancetype)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    [self setupCamera];
}
return self;
}

- (void)setupCamera {
if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    return;
}
if([self isAVCaptureActive]) {
    _captureQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.dmall.ScanQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    NSError *error = nil;
    _device  = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    _session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [self configSessionPreset];

    _output  = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [_output setVideoSettings:@{
                                (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
                                }];
    [_output setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];
    [_output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:_captureQueue];

    _input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_device error:&error];
    if ([_session canAddInput:_input]) {
        [_session addInput:_input];
    }
    if ([_session canAddOutput:_output]) {
        [_session addOutput:_output];
    }

}
else {
    [self showAccessAlert];
}  
}
```

And in the viewController, I set like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
DMVideoCamera *camera = [DMVideoCamera new];
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer =[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:camera.session];
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
camera.zoomFactor = 1.6;
[camera start];
}
```

If you want to run the project, please download the code from my github: [Demo code](https://github.com/dulingkang/DMScanCode).

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, just change setup to some get methods and it works, in my Github: https://github.com/dulingkang/DMScanCode